# Creating a Debian package from Python package via stdeb: what is .deb file?

Tags: python, django, packaging

After typing this command:

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

I get a folder deb_dist, which contains orig.tar.gz, debian.tar.gz and .dsc file. And where is .deb file?

Am I doing something wrong or this is right? I`m new in packaging and do not understand all details.

Comment: On which Operating System you are creating a package or running the above command?

Comment: have you installed [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb)?

Comment: There are two archives, orig.tar.contains just the same files as there are in the main folder, and the second archive .debian.tar.gz contains just files like changelog, rules etc.

Comment: Yes, I had installed it

Comment: apt-get install python-stdeb

Answer (score 0):

You should install dependence:

```
apt-get install python-stdeb fakeroot python-all
```

After typing the command:

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

The directory *deb_dist* will be contain deb package. You can look on http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-debian-packages-w-stdeb.html